# Where is the current instruction address stored in JVM, if the method currently being executed by the thread is native?

Tags: java, jvm

> If that method is not native, the pc register contains the address of the Java Virtual Machine instruction currently being executed. If the method currently being executed by the thread is native, the value of the Java Virtual Machine's pc register is undefined. -- from “The Java ® Virtual Machine Specification”

Is the current instruction stored in the pc register of CPU? And what kind of instruction set does native method execute?

Comment: *"And what kind of instruction set does native method execute?"* Native methods run using the native instruction set of the platform on which they're running -- 80x86, etc.

Comment: The JVM doesn’t store the current instruction of native code. The native code just works like native code works on that platform, i.e. the same way it would work without a JVM.